# A Paypal notification was refused because the connection to the confirmation server failed

Tags: paypal, notifications, joomla3.0

I am using Joomla and Hikashop with the Paypal plugin and Joomlabamboo's Rasa2 template. I am using a Paypal sandbox and I am getting the following email generated by Hikashop and sent to the email address set up in the shop configuration:

Hello,
A Paypal notification was refused because the connection to the confirmation server failed.

Check the documentation concerning this issue at www.hikashop.com/index.php?option=com_up...pal-error#connection
This notification was for the order E4 on the website www.mysite/
You can access the order details directly by clicking on the link below after logging in your back end:
www.mysite/administrator/index.php?optio...task=edit&order_id=4

The explanation is the following:
Connection to paypal failed

When your server receives a notification it needs first to confirm whether this notification comes from your payment gateway or not because it is always possible that a valid IP address has been injected and that someone else is tried to validate an order. So there is a mechanism in place to contact a paypal server HikaShop knows as being an official paypal server to confirm that it comes from paypal. If this connection fails, that means that either your hosting company is blocking outgoing connections from your server or you don't have the openssl option activated in your PHP configuration or that the paypal servers are down, the later being a lot less likely. So you should check that you website is able to make outgoing connections and that the SSL is activated. Also, we advise you to contact your hosting provider to ask them about their policies on outgoing connections. If they are not blocking them, then you might want to contact us via our forum as we might need to adapt our plugin to a change from paypal.

When I asked my host (Siteground) the said they were unable to locate any server-related reason for it.

Is it because I am using Paypal's sandbox? I am not receiving emails in the Notifications section in the Sandbox either.
Any suggestions?